# How to save Eigen::DiagonalMatrix in MarketIO format in Eigen?

Tags: c++, save, eigen, diagonal

Using `Eigen 3.2.1`, I am trying to save an `Eigen::DiagonalMatrix` in `MarketIO` format as below:

```
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include <Unsupported/Eigen/SparseExtra>
using namespace Eigen;
...

size_t n = XX;
DiagonalMatrix<num_t, Dynamic> W(n);
...
saveMarket(W, "W.txt"); // error propagates from here
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
MarketIO.h|236|error: 'const class Eigen::DiagonalMatrix<double, -1>' has no
member named 'nonZeros'
```

What is the problem here? Is this implemented at all for `Diagonal Matrices`?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: try 3.2.9 or 3.3-beta1 then

Comment: @kangshiyin: Are you sure it is there in 3.2.9+?

Comment: Nope! At least in `Eigen 3.2.9` also, `.nonZeros()` is not defined for `DiagonalMatrix` in `DiagonalMatrix.h` and still `MarketIO.h` uses `.nonZeros()`.

Comment: ok so it seems the unsupported part is too old...

Comment: it is just 3 arrays. you can save them manually.

Comment: @kangshiyin: Yeah! That seems the only way for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay! The only solution for now with minimal effort is to use the following:

```
saveMarketVector(W.diagonal(), "W.txt");
```